# LinQ Data Row and Column collection C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the row collection and the Column names as list , is there way to pass all the column names using the delegate to a single row and return the values as a collection?. 
or is there any other best way to accompolish this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying you have a `DataRow` and you want the value in each column?

Then all you need is this:

```
object[] values = row.ItemArray;
```

If you only want the values from *specific* columns, I'd recommend some LINQ magic to give them to you in the form of a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = GetDesiredColumnNames();

var values = columnNames
    .ToDictionary(name => name, name => row[name]);
```

Of course, you could also use this same LINQ magic to get a `Dictionary<string, object>` for *all* columns (if `object[]` isn't descriptive enough for your liking):

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = row.Table.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(column => column.ColumnName);

var values = columnNames
    .ToDictionary(name => name, name => row[name]);
```

Comment: Thats right Dan,The magic indeed worked awesome :-).Thank you.